# Calculating probability using combinations

Tags: probability, statistics

We have 50 chairs. 2 out of them are broken. What is probability that out of 5 taken chairs 4 or 5 are not broken?

We can calculate it by using $P(4 not broken) + P( 5 not broken)$

$P( 5 not broken ) = \frac{48}{50} * \frac{47}{49} * \frac{46}{48} * \frac{45}{47}* \frac{44}{46}$

But what about $P(4 not broken)$? If i take one chair probability that another chair will be broken/ not be broken is reduced. In this case can i use

$P(4 not broken) = C(5,4)* (\frac{48}{50} * \frac{47}{49} * \frac{46}{48} * \frac{45}{47})^{4} * \frac{2}{46}$ ?

Do i need to calcualte it using combinations?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the broken chair can be chosen either:

- first with probability: $$P_1 = \frac {2}{50}\times \frac {48}{49}\times \frac {47}{48}\times \frac {46}{47}\times \frac {45}{46} $$
- second with probability: $$P_2 = \frac {48}{50}\times \frac {2}{49}\times \frac {47}{48}\times \frac {46}{47}\times \frac {45}{46}$$

  Surely you can complete the other cases.

Comment: I am aware of this solution. But using combination i will have one * 2/46.
Thats why i am not sure if i can use combinations

Comment: @trolkura Note that we can chose 4 non broken chairs out of the 48, giving us: $\binom {48}{4} $ ways, a broken chair from 2: in $\binom21$ ways, out of a total of choosing 5 from 50: $\binom {50}{5} $ ways. What does this imply?

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I would calculate it this way:

Since it's without replacement and without order:

$P(A)=\frac{\binom {48} {k}\binom {2} {k}}{\binom {50} {5}}$

Insert K value 4 and 5 and your solutions are:

$P(4 not brokenchairs)=\frac{\binom {48} {4}\binom {2} {1}}{\binom {50} {5}}=\frac{389160}{2118760}=\frac{9}{49}=.18367$

$P(5 not brokenchairs)=\frac{\binom {48} {5}\binom {2} {0}}{\binom {50} {5}}=\frac{1712304}{2118760}=\frac{198}{245}=.80816$

Comment: I didn't see @Rohan 's  fine answer since I was typing (and struggling with the Latex binomial code) my own answer. I'll let mine stay since the formulas is set up different.